# Django I want to make comments on category posts

Tags: django

I want to make comments on posts. I found a lot of monual, but it either does not fit or does not work.
I need to create a separate function for adding and viewing comments in posts. I don't understand how to make a separate comment function and display it in the post template. Need a simple, elegant solution to the problem.

```
    class season(models.Model):
        slug = models.SlugField(max_length=266, unique=True, db_index=True, verbose_name=('SLUG'))
        ...

        def __str__(self):
            return self.slug

        def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse('seasonpost', kwargs={'seasonpost_slug': self.slug, 'episodepost_slug': self.slug})



    class episode(models.Model):
        slug = models.SlugField(max_length=266, unique=True, db_index=True, verbose_name=('SLUG'))
        ...
        
        cat = models.ForeignKey('season', on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.slug
        
        
        def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse('episodepost', kwargs={'seasonpost_slug': self.slug, 'episodepost_slug': self.slug})
            
            
    class Comment(models.Model):
        post = models.ForeignKey(episode,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
        name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
        email = models.EmailField()
        body = models.TextField()
        created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

        class Meta:
            ordering = ['created_on']

        def __str__(self):
            return 'Comment {} by {}'.format(self.body, self.name)
            
            
    FORM.PY
        from .models import Comment
        from django import forms
        
        class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
            class Meta:
            model = Comment
            fields = ('name', 'body')
            

    Views
        from .forms import *
        from .models import *
        ...

    def ContentSeason(request, seasonpost_slug):
        seasonpages = get_list_or_404(season, slug=seasonpost_slug)
        homepages=home.objects.all()
        seasonspages=seasons.objects.all()
        season_menu=season.objects.all()
        episodepost = episode.objects.filter()
        seasonpages=season.objects.filter(slug=seasonpost_slug)
        return render(request, 'content/season.html',{
            'season':seasonpages, 
            'episode': episodepost,})



    def ContentEpisode(request, seasonpost_slug, episodepost_slug):
        episodepost = episode.objects.filter(slug=episodepost_slug, cat__slug=seasonpost_slug)
        current_episode = get_object_or_404(episodepost, slug=episodepost_slug, cat__slug=seasonpost_slug)
        previous_episode = episode.objects.filter(cat__slug=seasonpost_slug, pk__lt=current_episode.pk).first()
        next_episode = episode.objects.filter(cat__slug=seasonpost_slug, pk__gt=current_episode.pk).first()
        
        return render(request, 'content/episode.html', {
            'episode': episodepost,
            'current_episode': current_episode,
            'previous_episode': previous_episode,
            'next_episode': next_episode,
    })


        path('', views.ContentHome, name='homepage'),
        path('seasons', views.ContentSeasons),
        path('seasons/<slug:seasonpost_slug>', views.ContentSeason, name='episode-detail'),
        path('seasons/<slug:seasonpost_slug>/<slug:episodepost_slug>', views.ContentEpisode, name='episode-detail'),
        
    Template
    
        <div class="contaiter__b">
            <h3>Comments</h3>

        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try defining those views functions;

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import episode, Comment

def episode_detail(request, seasonpost_slug, episodepost_slug):
    post = get_object_or_404(episode, slug=episodepost_slug, 
    cat__slug=seasonpost_slug)
    comments = post.comments.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.POST.get('name')
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        body = request.POST.get('body')
        Comment.objects.create(post=post, name=name, email=email, body=body)
    return render(request, 'episode_detail.html', {'post': post, 'comments': 
                  comments})

def add_comment_to_episode(request, seasonpost_slug, episodepost_slug):
    post = get_object_or_404(episode, slug=episodepost_slug, 
         cat__slug=seasonpost_slug)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.POST.get('name')
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        body = request.POST.get('body')
        Comment.objects.create(post=post, name=name, email=email, body=body)
    return redirect('episode_detail', seasonpost_slug=seasonpost_slug, 
       episodepost_slug=episodepost_slug)
```